# Banner motd в Cisco IOS

Tags: настройка, cisco, cisco-packet-tracer, cisco-ios

Я новичок в сетях и изучаю базовые настройки устройств `cisco`. Возник вопрос относительно команды `banner motd` (сообщение текущего дня). Возможно, знатоки знают ответ. Так вот, как переносить сообщение на новую строку? Или это невозможно?
Также буду рад просто предположениям, как можно перенести здесь текст на новую строку.
П.с. вид команды:
`banner motd #Some text#`
Впоследствии перед получением доступа к устройству будет отображаться текст:
`Some text.`
Вместо `#` - может быть абсолютно любой символ (ну или так заявляют в курсах по `cisco`).
Цель: сделать перенос строки

> Some
>   text

Comment: [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Udr5GP8J00), [дока (Usage Guidelines)](https://www.cisco.com/c/m/en_us/techdoc/dc/reference/cli/n5k/commands/banner-motd.html).

Comment: banner motd #Some \n\ntext#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[документация cisco по motd banner](https://www.cisco.com/c/m/en_us/techdoc/dc/reference/cli/n5k/commands/banner-motd.html)

> To create a multiple-line MOTD banner, press Enter before typing the delimiting character to start a new line. You can enter up to 40 lines of text.

В Вашем случае:

```
R1(config)#banner motd #some (нажать Enter)
Enter TEXT message.  End with the character '#'
text #
```